# How to autocomplete in CtrlP search bar?

Tags: vim, ctrlp

If I want to create a new file `config/initializers/NEW_FILE.rb` under CTRLP,

I need to type the full path, how could I use the fuzzy search function to auto-complete the  `config/initializers/` in the typing area.

That is, I can type `cfg/ini_` then I can type some key to auto complete `config/initializers/`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't ask for that but you could do the following *without* CtrlP:

```
:e co*/in*<Tab>NEW_FILE.rb<CR>
```

You'll need `longest` in the values of `wildmode`, though:

```
set wildmode=longest
```

Comment: If it could done under ctrlP , I think it will be more friendly, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

CtrlP will autocomplete the current path segment when you hit the `<Tab>` key.